# My Toast only goes through else statement Android Java

Tags: java, android, if-statement, toast

Still a beginner in Android development. I'm trying to create a simple 'score results' app where the user has to enter their score and their results appear as a toast accordingly. The problem is my Toast only goes for an else statement regardless of what score the user entered. What am I doing so wrong? Please help.

int score = 100;

```
public void checkResults (View view){

    Log.i("Results","Button Tapped");

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    TextView editTextNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(score < 29){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You got an F", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (score >= 30 && score <= 39){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You got E", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Where are you re-assigning the `score` ? I don't see it in your given code.

Comment: I would assume you are not changing the value of score variable? Just a quick idea in my mind

Comment: There should be an edittext or another kind of input view, you read the value from that or asign that value to score.

Comment: Show us where you are setting the score variable

Comment: Because you set the variable score as 100, that is why the code goes to the part of else. In your code, when score larger than 39, the code will go to the else part.

Answer (score 0):

Use EditText instead of TextView to get score as input from the user. Inside the onClickListener() of the button assign input value to score variable before if-else statements using

```
score = Integer.parseInt(editext.getText().toString())
```